# How i get user chat information

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

i have 2 tables one is "Chat" which only have on column id
the second one i have is 
`CREATE TABLE`chat_user`(`
id`int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,`
user_id`varchar(45) NOT NULL,`
chat_id`int(11) DEFAULT NULL,`
created_at`timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,`
updated_at`timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;`

what i do is i create a row in chat table then i store 2 roes in chat user with two user ids and one chat id

now how i have 2 user id how i get there chat id ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answers assumes that you already know the ids of both users, and you want to find all chats in which both of those users participated.  One approach is to aggregate the `chat_user` table by `chat_id`, and then assert that a given chat involved both users:

```
SELECT chat_id
FROM chat_user
GROUP BY chat_id
HAVING MIN(user_id) = <user_id_1> AND MAX(user_id) = <user_id_2>;
--                         |___________________________|__ replace with actual values
```

Answer (score 0):

you should do

```
SELECT DISCTINCT(chat_id) from CHAT_USERS where user_id IN (someuser_id1, someuser_id2)
```

to get the chat_ids for the 2 users.